# Display data in Dropdown using model with List<selectListItem>

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC and would like to bind data in DropDownList using Model. But I'm not sure how to get into that. 
Below is my code

--Model

```
public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Qualification { get; set; }
    public string CountryID { get; set; }
    public string StateID { get; set; }
    public string CityID { get; set; }
    public List<SelectList> CountryList { get; set; }
    //public List<SelectListItem> Country { get; set; }
    public List<SelectList> StateList { get; set; }
    public List<SelectList> CityList { get; set; }
```

--View

```
<tr>
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(s => s.Name)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(s => s.Qualification)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.Qualification, new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(s => s.Country)</td>
        <td>@Html.DropDownList("Country", new SelectList(Model.CountryList), "Select Country", new { @Class = "form-control" })</td>
    </tr>
```

--Controller

```
 public ActionResult DisplayView(EmployeeDetails.Models.DisplayModel dm)
    {
        EmployeeDetails.Models.DisplayModel obj = new EmployeeDetails.Models.DisplayModel();
        List<SelectListItem> CountryList = obj.CountryDetails(dm);
        //var CountryList = obj.CountryDetails(dm);

        obj.CountryList = new SelectList(CountryList, "Value", "Text");

        return View();
    }
```

In model, I have a method(CountryDetails) to return COuntrylist as List from Database.

I'm getting error in the below line to assign values to the list in model.

```
 obj.CountryList = new SelectList(CountryList, "Value", "Text");
```

Please help me out to display the value correctly in Dropdown.

Comment: First your not return a view to your model so `CountryList` is `null` (hence the exception) - its `return View(obj)`. Next its pointless to create a 2nd identical `Ienumerable<SelectListItem>` in the view using `new SelectList(...)`. And third, your model does not contain a property named `Country` - its `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryID, Model.CountryList, "Select Country", new { .. })`

Comment: And why do you have a `EmployeeDetails.Models.DisplayModel dm` parameter in your GET method? And your model should not contain that method. Use a service.

Comment: Hi, Thankyou... It works now. But when I try to Convert and assign CountryList to obj.Countrylist the exception still exists because of conversion.  Below is the error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>' "

Comment: What line throws that exception? And why are you doing that anyway? The `DropDownListFor() method requires a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` as its 2nd parameter. You already have one so why are you using `new SelectList()` to convert to to exactly the same `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` again.

Comment: The proeprty in your model should be `public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CountryList { get; set; }` and the code to populate it should be somethng like `obj.CountryList = db.Countries.Select(x => new SelectListItem{ Value = x.CountryId.ToString(), Text = x.Name}` (and remove any method in your model that generates it)

Comment: @Lakshmi is below answer resolved your issue

Answer (score 0):

I have just replicated you issue and made some changes to make it run.

In Model i have made change from `list<SelectList>` to `List<SelectListItem>`
after that i have PopulateCountry dropdownlist hardcoded data in controller which you can change it by replacing it with database.

After populating dropdownlist next using jquery ajax i have populated states and city dropdownlist.

> Model

```
public class DisplayModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Choose Country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Qualification { get; set; }
    public string CountryID { get; set; }
    public string StateID { get; set; }
    public string CityID { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> CountryList { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> StateList { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> CityList { get; set; }
}
```

> Controller Code

```
 public class DemoController : Controller
{
    // GET: Demo
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        DisplayModel obj = new DisplayModel();
        obj.CountryList = PopulateCountry();
        return View(obj);
    }

    private static List<SelectListItem> PopulateCountry()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> li = new List<SelectListItem>();
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Select", Value = "0" });
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "India", Value = "1" });
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Srilanka", Value = "2" });
        return li;
    }

    public JsonResult GetStates(string id)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> states = new List<SelectListItem>();
        switch (id)
        {
            case "1":
                states.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Select", Value = "0" });
                states.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "ANDAMAN & NIKOBAR ISLANDS", Value = "1" });
                states.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "MAHARASHTRA", Value = "2" });
                break;
        }
        return Json(new SelectList(states, "Value", "Text"));
    }

    public JsonResult GetCity(string id)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> City = new List<SelectListItem>();
        switch (id)
        {
            case "2":
                City.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Select", Value = "0" });
                City.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "MUMBAI", Value = "1" });
                City.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "PUNE", Value = "2" });
                City.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "KOLHAPUR", Value = "3" });
                City.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "RATNAGIRI", Value = "4" });
                City.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "NAGPUR", Value = "5" });
                City.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "JALGAON", Value = "6" });
                break;
        }
        return Json(new SelectList(City, "Value", "Text"));
    }
}
```

> View

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.DisplayModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(s => s.Country)</td>
        <td>@Html.DropDownList("Country", Model.CountryList, "Select Country", new { @Class = "form-control" })</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>State</td>
        <td>@Html.DropDownList("State", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a State", new { style = "width:250px", @class = "form-control" }) </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>City</td>
        <td>@Html.DropDownList("city", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a city", new { style = "width:250px", @class = "form-control" })   </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Dropdownlist Selectedchange event
        $("#Country").change(function () {
            $("#State").empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetStates")', // we are calling json method

                dataType: 'json',

                data: { id: $("#Country").val() },
                // here we are get value of selected country and passing same valueas inputto json method GetStates.

                success: function (states) {
                    // states contains the JSON formatted list
                    // of states passed from the controller

                    $.each(states, function (i, state) {
                        $("#State").append('<option value="' + state.Value + '">' + state.Text + '</option>');
                        // here we are adding option for States

                    });
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve states.' + ex);
                }
            });
            return false;
        })
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Dropdownlist Selectedchange event
        $("#State").change(function () {
            $("#city").empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetCity")',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { id: $("#State").val() },
                success: function (citys) {
                    // states contains the JSON formatted list
                    // of states passed from the controller
                    $.each(citys, function (i, city) {
                        $("#city").append('<option value="' + city.Value + '">' + city.Text + '</option>');
                    });
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve states.' + ex);
                }
            });
            return false;
        })
    });
</script>
```