# Loading Second dropdownlist in onchange event of the first dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I would like to post a form in the onchange event of the first dropdown to load the second dropdown.

#### View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>

        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(s => s.Country)</td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(s => s.Country, Model.Country, "Select Country", new { @Class = "form-control", @OnChange = "document.location.href = '/Display/StateSelection?Country=' + this.options[this.SelectedIndex].Value;' " })</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(s => s.State)</td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(s => s.State, Model.State, new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
            @*<td>@Html.DropDownListFor(s => s.State, Model.State, "Select State", new { @Class = "form-control", @onchange = "document.location.href ='/Display/CitySelection?StateID=' + this.options[this.SelectedIndex].Value;" })</td>*@
        </tr>
        @*<tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(s => s.City)</td>
            <td>@Html.ListBoxFor(s => s.City, Model.City, new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
        </tr>*@
    </table>

    @*<input type="submit" value="DisplayData" />*@
    @*<input type="submit" value="DisplayData" onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("DisplayView","Display")'"/>*@
}
```

#### Controller

```
    public ActionResult DisplayView()
    {
        DisplayModel obj = new DisplayModel();
        string CountryID = "0";
        //string StateID = "0";
        List<SelectListItem> CountryList = obj.CountryDetails();
        List<SelectListItem> StateList = obj.StateDetails(CountryID);
        //List<SelectListItem> CityList = obj.CityDetails(StateID);
        //var CountryList = obj.CountryDetails(dm);

        obj.Country = CountryList;// new SelectList(CountryList, "Value", "Text");
        obj.State = StateList;
        //obj.City = CityList;
        TempData["CountryList"] = CountryList;

        return View("DisplayView",obj);
    }


    public ActionResult StateSelection(String Country)
    {
        DisplayModel obj = new DisplayModel();
        obj.Country = (List < SelectListItem >)TempData["CountryList"];
        obj.State = obj.StateDetails(Country);
        TempData.Keep("CountryList");
        return View("DisplayView",obj);
    }


From view, I'm passing the selected value to the controller, from controller calling the logic from model to load the list based on the country selected.
```

When I submit the form it is working as expected. Can anyone tell me how to load the second dropdown based on the value selected in the first dropdown in OnChange event without submitting the form using "submit button"

Comment: Why are you not using Ajax POST request

Comment: Take a look at this [How to create cascading drop-down list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46954959/how-to-create-cascading-drop-down-list)

Comment: Study the code in [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym)

Comment: Check you last post there is answer you do not closed you first question and ask same again Question link :-  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47350251/display-data-in-dropdown-using-model-with-listselectlistitem/47353457#47353457